# Failed to start and then listen on the port

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I have an NodeJS app that I want to deploy on Google Cloud Run.
I have Google Cloud Build configured to build container from dockerfile whenever something has been pushed ona master branch and after build Cloud Run will run new revision.

My problem is that every time I want to deploy my app I got the following error:
`Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable.`

Cloud Run have configured `containerPort: 8080`

In my dockerfile I'm exposing port 8080 and in nodejs I have set up simply http server using

```js
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Just for testing purposes\n');
});

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 8080;
server.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log('Hello world listening on port', port);
});
```

my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-alpine

# Install app dependencies.
COPY package.json /src/package.json
WORKDIR /src
RUN npm install

# Cloud Run requrement
EXPOSE 8080

COPY index.js /src/index.js

ENTRYPOINT "node index.js"
```

Have I missed something? This is my first time working with google cloud so I'm sure there is something I need to configure that I don't know about yet.

Comment: If you perform a `node index.js` on your workstation, does it work?

Comment: yeah and sorry. I have figured out it already. my problem was in Dockerfile. I had to replace `ENTRYPOINT "node index.js"` with `CMD ["node", "index.js"]`. Don't know why this worked tho.

Comment: @ciekals11 please add your solution as an answer to your question and accept it so that others in the community can refer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my Dockerfile.
I had to change `ENTRYPOINT "node index.js"` to `CMD ["node", "index.js"]`.
Bu reason behind it is still unknown to me.